# Scala + Android IDE

Tags: android, scala, ide, android-ide

I am an eclipse user and android developer.

I am trying to develop android applications using scala. I managed to do an hello world once in eclipse and now I am trying to do it with Intellij IDEA, so I can choose the best option. I managed to run simple scala examples in Intellij and I am trying now to create an android application there.

The problem is: Eclipse seems a lot more EASY to build an android application with scala than Intellij. For what I have seen you need to use SBT and install a lot of "extras" to get things done.

I have seen some questions here about IDEs for Scala. But didn't find a **recent** question about the combo Scala + Android.

So, my question is... Should I give Intellij a try or eclipse is just fine? Is it possible to run the application on my smartphone easly with Intellij?

Comment: Android ui in scala is slow and does not work for perfomance reasons( I mean real scala using impilicit's and so on), I ended with scala project packed to jar and added to android project(android is view+controller, scala is model). Choose IDE which you know better for quickstart.

Comment: I haven't encountered performance issues with Scala used in Adnroid UI.

Comment: Packing scala as a logic layer was one solution I thought. I supose that the jar generated is similar to the jars generated with Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried Intellij Idea but it wasn't as simple as Eclipse. You should prefer eclipse rather than using this Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried Eclipse with Android IDE so I cannot compare. I use IntelliJ 10.5 for Android development with Scala. And it just works perfectly.

All you need is to download Scala plugin with IntelliJ's build-in plugin manager. Android support is installed by default in Idea 10.5.

I can highly recommend Idea 10.5 for Android development with Scala.

Comment: You can run directly on a external device like eclipse?

Comment: Sure you can. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/choosing-the-target-device-manually.html#actualDevice

Comment: To finish this subject... I saw some tutorials that said to install SBT and other "add-ons" to work with IntelliJ. Are you sure I only need Scala plugin? Should I start an Android Project or a Scala project?

Comment: Create Android project then add Scala support to it (just few clicks on the project structure). Or even better create Android Maven project with configured Scala plugin.

Comment: I must be honest. I still can't do it. I don't know how you guys like this IDE. I managed to run an Android example, then tried to convert to scala. I was able to run it once and app crashed giving me: ERROR/APPY(4238): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.newsrep.net .

Comment: I don't know your particular project so I can't help you with that. All I'm saying is that Idea 10.5 + Android + Scala works perfectly for me.